# Avoiding \r\n\ on mysql import

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I have the following code to import a CSV file in to a MYSQL database but am having a few issues on import.

```
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "resultsimport.csv"; // Name of your CSV file
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
$i = 0;
while (!feof($csvfile)) {
$csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile);
$csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
$insert_csv = array();
$insert_csv['ID'] = $csv_array[0];
$insert_csv['SerialNo'] = $csv_array[1];
$insert_csv['ChannelNo'] = $csv_array[2];
$insert_csv['IL850'] = $csv_array[3];
$insert_csv['IL1300'] = $csv_array[4];
$insert_csv['IL1310'] = $csv_array[5];
$insert_csv['IL1550'] = $csv_array[6];
$insert_csv['RL850'] = $csv_array[7];
$insert_csv['RL1300'] = $csv_array[8];
$insert_csv['RL1310'] = $csv_array[9];
$insert_csv['RL1550'] = $csv_array[10];
$query = "INSERT INTO results(ID,SerialNo,ChannelNo,IL850,IL1300,IL1310,IL1550,RL850,RL1300,RL1310,RL1550)
VALUES('".$insert_csv['ID']."','".$insert_csv['SerialNo']."','".$insert_csv['ChannelNo']."','".$insert_csv['IL850']."','".$insert_csv['IL1300']."','".$insert_csv['IL1310']."','".$insert_csv['IL1550']."','".$insert_csv['RL850']."','".$insert_csv['RL1300']."','".$insert_csv['RL1310']."','".$insert_csv['RL1550']."')";
$n=mysql_query($query, $connect );
$i++;
}
fclose($csvfile);

echo "File data successfully imported to database";
mysql_close($connect);
```

Here is an example of the first two lines from the CSV file:

```
ID,SerialNo,ChannelNo,IL850,IL1300,IL1310,IL1550,RL850,RL1300,RL1310,RL1550
1405230001-A-MTP-1-01,1405230001,A-MTP-1-1,0.320,0.150,,,,,,
```

As you can see there is only data in two of the columns, but on some imports there will be data to import in the final column.

The problem happens when there is no data in that final column, my import process adds in \r\n\ to the database.

How can I avoid that?

I also end up with a blank line on import at the end.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5 has a built in function to parse CSV for you, [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). It is better than relying on explode (which is naive about text enclosed with quotes that could contain commas. An empty line will result in an empty `$data` array, so test for that and skip them

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($csvfile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if (empty($data) continue;
    // rest of data manipulation continues
}
```

**Sidenote:** you should not be using the `mysql_*` family of functions. That extension has long been deprecated. You should be using mysqli or PDO to connect to your database and using prepared queries to guard against SQL injection attacks.